# Pantheon Not Completely Installed?

Tags: desktop-environments, settings, launchpad, pantheon

I have just installed the pantheon shell today, and I have not found any help with this yet. I am not just a random noob, i use a bunch of other shells and i also have a few development applications on my copy of ubuntu. But ever since ive opened up pantheon, i cannot find settings or this thing called the launchpad. (if the launchpad is the app drawer up in the upper left corner, or if its the dock. i have it, if thats not what launchpad is, then i cant access it.) I can only change my wallpaper by going back to unity, gnome, or KDE. There is a system settings in the power menu (upper right), but it only has Language Support, Ubuntu One, Additional Drivers, And Printing. I can still access the full ubuntu settings in GNOME of Unity. But thats it. I installed in the terminal, uninstalled, and reinstalled using the software center.

Please Help Me If Any Of You Can!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install dconf-tools.
2. Open dconf-editor. Go through the tree org.pantheon.cerbere.
3. Remove "pantheon-wallpaper" if present and add 'nautilus -n', 'gala' if its missing.
4. Now right click, set as background etc should work.

Also, open from terminal: switchboard . Full settings should work now.

In my case the half setting issue is there as well as the log out, shut down etc options are not working! Also, the options are blurred!